# Laravel event listener on autologin (remember me)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-events

In my Laravel 7.3 project I want to fire an event after a user login. This event should also be fired when a user has autologin ('Remember me'/Cookie Token) activated.

Login via form is: (EventServiceProvider.php)

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\Auth\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],
```

In a forum post I read that this event won't be triggered on autologin (Remember Me) but there was no solution since the thread was abandoned. Has anyone solved this and can give me a hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: is it working for you for normal login

Comment: @JohnLobo to be honest I just read about it to clarify before implementing it. I haven't tested anything so far. But I plan to implement it until tomorrow so let me get back to you about that.

Comment: i have tried it with login it will trigger in laravel 8 hope it works in laravel 7 too and browser remembered password it works not sure about auto login didnt tried that

Comment: @JohnLobo thx for testing this man, I will check it tomorrow

Comment: in the meantime I found an alternate way, where I don't need to have a trigger on autologin, so I'm leaving this alone. Maybe I will come back to this another time, but let's be honest, probably not.